# How to set legend value to current date value in annotation google chart

Tags: php, google-visualization

I just want to set current date value as legend default value (i.e today date is 25/1/2015 then it will selected default legend value as 9. I can not find configuration to make it as default value as current date. I am using with google annotation chart

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['annotationchart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'WTI');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nat Gas FOB US');

    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2015, 0, 1), 5],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 4), 1],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 7), 3],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 10), 5],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 13), 3],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 16), 7],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 19), 3],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 22), 4],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 25), 9],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 28), 8],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 31), 6]
    ]);
    data.addRows(usdeurl);


    var firstday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var lastday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31);
    var options = {
        displayAnnotations: true,
        zoomStartTime: firstday,
        zoomEndTime: lastday,
        highlightDot: 

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: You mean the hilightDot should be todays?

Comment: Yes i want to set today's value as legend value default